# EF Saving related data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, entity-framework-4

I'm quite new to EF and I'm still trying to wrap my head around it all - I'm used to building stored procedures and calling them rather than LINQ-SQL, so bear with me!

I am trying to build a simple image manager which other entities can related into. So something like
`Entity 1` -has 1-> `Image Collection` -has many-> `Images`
`Entity 2` -has 1-> `Image Collection` -has many-> `Images` etc...

Currently I'm trying to do the Image Collection -> Images side of things, but I'm running into some really frustrating issues when trying to save existing data.
On my model I have my business method to `AddImage` to the list of images on the collection ala

```
public class ImageCollection : Entity
{
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }

    public void AddImage(Image Image)
    {
        this.Images.Add(Image);
    }
}
```

...and then a service updates the collection - which is all fine when adding new images.

The problem is when updating information. Now I know that if I am relating information I can attach to something existing if I'm in some sort of loop, like:

```
// get tag from context
var image = new Image { Id = 1 } 

// attach into the entity
_service.Attach<Image>(image);

// attach image to collection
collection.Images.Add(image);
```

However when I've already got the images inside `collection.Images`, how the bloomin' heck can I commit/save my collection in the database without it trying to duplicate everything?  I've tried attaching...

```
// attach any previously referenced images so they don't get duplicated
foreach (var image in Collection.Images.Where(image => image.Id > 0).ToList())
{
    Image i = new Image { Id = image.Id };
    (_imageCollectionRepository as GenericRespository<ImageCollection>).Attach<Image>(i);
}
```

I've tried setting it's state (this is inside a called `SetAsUnchangedState<T>(T item){}`)

```
_context.Entry<T>(item).State = System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged;
```

But nothing, just errors, `An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager` or `AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object’s key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager.` and probably others.

**EDIT 1.**

Steps I am currently taking - if this helps...

1. Controller receives an `ImageCollection` entity and it's list of
   `Images` as per the model at the top of this question. It is then
   sent to the view as a viewmodel (CollectionID and List)
2. The view shows these images and their properties (just title) and
   it's primary key. Which is then POSTed. The controller then gets the image collection from the service `ImageCollection collection = _imageService.FindCollectionById(model.CollectionID)` and adds each image in the view model through the business logic.
3. The controller then passes this ImageCollection to the service for updating. This is where it's all going a bit wrong I reckon, as I the controller and business logic should be persistance ignorant - and yes I know I am currently getting the ImageCollection by it's ID in the controller to begin with! I'll probably just pass the view model to the service, or create a message request later down the line.

**EDIT 2**
I've now sort of worked out where I was going wrong, I've ended up with the following code, it's not pretty at the moment as I am trying to work it all out. But is this all essentially correct? Or is there a more efficient way of doing this?

```
public void UpdateCollection(ViewModels.ImageCollectionViewModel model)
    {
        // get collection
        ImageCollection collection = FindCollectionById(model.CollectionID);

        if (model.Images != null)
        {
            GenericRespository<Image> temp_repository = new GenericRespository<Image>();

            // add images
            foreach (Image i in model.Images)
            {
                if (i.Id > 0)
                {
                    temp_repository.Attach<Image>(i);
                    temp_repository.Update(image);                        
                }
                else
                {
                    collection.Images.Add(i);
                }
            }

            temp_repository.SaveChanges();
        }

        _imageCollectionRepository.Update(collection);
        _imageCollectionRepository.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Where am I going so very wrong? :( Thanks.

Comment: What is that you are trying to achieve? In your comments, you mention 'attaching so they don't get duplicated'. Is that the actual problem?

Comment: It's in the title - saving related data. Thought I'd detailed the problem enough :-/ Being able to update a parent object (collection) in the database with related data (images) that already exists in the database. Also being able to save new images that are added through the business logic.

Comment: The problem is that by default, you don't have to do anything to make sure that existing data isn't duplicated. If an entity is loaded, you can just change its properties and save your changes

Comment: Thanks Wouter. Can you define "entity is loaded"? Do you mean if I get that entity by it's primary key, and then set it it's EntityState to unchanged?

Comment: you don't have to explicitly tell you have changed a record, that is automatically handled by the DBcontext.

Comment: Problem is though, where do I "load" my entity? I should have mentioned (my bad), that I'm actually trying to have a layered approach with my model + business logic, service, repository. So all my images are being added in the business logic when a form is posted to a controller, passed to the service, which then performs the updates and saves the changes. Does that mean I need ridiculous calls to the services to get the image by id's primary key id (so it's EntityKey is not NULL) and then add the image to the list in the business logic? My business logic should not be concerned with this!...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EF, every entity object have an identifier called `EntityKey` (that you can see its read-only value at runtime). So when you get for example 10 Images from your database, each of these records will have a different unique key. This EntityKey serves as the ID for those records.

When adding a new record, the EntityKey is null. That allows the DBcontext to know this is a record to be inserted.
However a record that came from the database, has an EntityKey value.

In your situation (depending on the error message), you are trying to save existing data (with same primary keys as your database data) but their entityKey is null, in which case are considered as new records in DBcontext, but of course will conflict with your database data.

The error may be caused by the fact that you are creating an new Image (or List) to bind your image (or List), something like

```
Image i = new Image { Id = image.Id };
```

which is not correct. Use instead

```
Image i = image ;
```

I hope this is clear.

#### Edit based on your comment

Attach, not only get the pre-existing Item but also update its properties based on the item you attached. At that level, if the item you are attaching already exists in the DBContext (this is done by comparing the EntityKeys) then it's fine. But in your case, it is trying to attach that Item which has a null EntityKey (in that case the item is considered an inserted Item), at the same time this inserted Item has a Primary Key that already exists for another Item (which is technically the same record in the database, but has a different EntityKey).

debug your code and check the entity key before/after updating the item to check its value, just to make sure it hasn't changed

[image]

Comment: Thanks Boomer, I didn't actually realise it uses an internal key and that primary key has no relevance in the EF side of things. Does this EntityKey vary depending on it's parent? So if I had a new collection referencing the same image (same primary key) for instance, would it have a different Entity Key because it's collection was different? In other words, if a single entity is related to from different entities, does it have the same EntityKey or different EntityKey for each Entity (parent) -> entity (single) relationship? Make sense?

Comment: Just to clear things, the EntityKey is not by Entity but by Entity instance. And yes, an instance will have the same key (as a database record)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that for me Boomer

Comment: no prob. If it answers your question please don't forget to set it correct :)

Comment: Hmmmm. Are you saying that the .Attach should be doing it's job then? Attach (correct me if I am wrong) tells EF to get a reference to the pre-exiting item, which when I then do collection.Images.Add(image) in the service - not business method, that it's obviously trying to re-add this reference, which will fail? And get an error such as `An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager`

Comment: Hi @Boomer thanks for your help on this, I've made an edit to my code - I think I am almost there. Could you have a quick look at it to see if it makes sense and/or advise where I am doing unnecessary steps...

Comment: I never worked EF on MVVM but this should work as long as the Item being saved has its entitykey preserved. Check my edit.

Comment: Thanks boomer, I was actually trying to find that EntityKey, but couldn't find it. I was looking in the wrong place. Thanks.

Comment: I've realised where I've been going wrong now, I think I've been thinking that EF is cleverer than I initially thought. It just needs some gentle encouragement to do some things :) Your answers, whilst not my solution, have helped me massively. So thanks Boomer! :)